# how loop through each dataset tables in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a dataset of three tables and i am doing loop through the dataset  and creating excel worksheet
this is the piece of code

```
Using wbs As New XLWorkbook()
    For Each dtperson As DataTable In dspatient.Tables
        'Add DataTable as Worksheet.
        wbs.Worksheets.Add(dtperson)
    Next

    wbs.SaveAs(finalPath)
                
End Using
```

now this `wbs.Worksheets.Add(dtperson)` is accepts only `datatable` now i want to loop it for two tables only like for `dspatient.Tables(0)` and `dspatient.Tables(1)`

Comment: You mean your question is how to populate 1 worksheet with the contents of 2 different tables? Or you want to create 2 worksheets, but only for 2 of the 3 tables in your dataset, and ignore the 3rd one?

Answer (score 1):

> i have a dataset of three tables .... now i want to loop it for two tables only

If you don't want to loop all but part of a collection, don't use a `For Each` but a `For`-loop:

```
For i As int32 = 0 To dspatient.Tables.Count - 2
    wbs.Worksheets.Add(dspatient.Tables(i))
Next
```

or, if you know that the tables exist and they are only 2, add them directly:

```
wbs.Worksheets.Add(dspatient.Tables(0))
wbs.Worksheets.Add(dspatient.Tables(1))
```